# System IO exception even though file is added in Visual studio C#

Tags: c#, filenotfoundexception

I have a project into which I added a JSON file, but when I try to read the file in code I get this error.

```
Could not find file 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express\\client_secret.json'.
"ExceptionType": "System.IO.FileNotFoundException"
```

I have the file added in like this.

I can access it when I copy the full path and then read it.

[image]

Comment: @PranayRana It didnt work at first because it gave me an error saying a Folder was missing - api . So I added that folder and added the file into it. Now it works.

Comment: Make an edit to answer like adding Server.MapPath(~/client._secret.json) because thats what helped me.

Comment: done updated ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its Asp.NEt or WEBAPI, i.e. its Web application you can access path by using `Server.MapPath` method.

Example : `Server.MapPath("~/script/data.txt")`//this locate file in your script folder on sever

for the folder under than website you need to do like this

```
Server.MapPath(~/client._secret.json) //here ~ sign means relative path from root
```

Server.MapPath method gives you physical path of your file on server machine.